# How can i get sample dataset of Google contacts with all of its field populated to test my project?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-data-api, google-data

These are few fields used to represent google contact.
https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?csw=1#gdContactKind,
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference

Is there any way i can get a sample datasets for this fields which can be imported to my gmail account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GData API is used by the Google Contact API (for read and write)

The datasets you can get on these docs are both right.

I can show you an sample working for me, written in `atom:xml`

```
    <entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
      <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' 
          term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
      <title>My Mail Contact</title>
      <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work' primary='true' address='saurabh.agrawal@gmail.coom'/>
    </entry>
```

Comment: .Yes,but the dataset given is scattered. What i am really looking for is some kind of big google contacts database in probably .cvs format file which I can import to my account and do testing for my project. 
Manually adding and entering all the fields into contacts can be a cumbersome task.

Comment: Oh OK !
I made a CSV with just name contact. https://pastebin.com/QvYiNr5b
Go to : https://www.google.com/contacts/#contacts (Old version is important: you can't import contacts from new version).
Wait a little, then move your contact to the group "My Contacts".
And there is, you got +2000 contacts on your account.

I made it with Google Sheet and exported in .CSV

Comment: .I didnt get . these are all empty fields . i need some data with all relevant fields populated. Can you please help more here ?

Comment: It's like an Excel sheet work. I won't fill some cells instead of you. I can explain you how to achieve this:
Export at least one contact from contacts.google.com in CSV. Edit this CSV with values in Excel or Google Sheet or others. Save this new CSV and import it into Google Contacts

Comment: Oh got it. I guess I'll have to do it this way only.
Thanks for the help zooly.

Comment: Good luck with google api :)